# Is it possible to download a Ruby gem without installing it automatically?

Tags: ruby, download, rubygems

When I download something using `gem` I'd like to be able to just download the gem, and then choose whether or not I want to install it. I'm asking this because I'd like to install a particular gem on more than one computers ( without installing from the internet on each one ).

Comment: If you are using RVM as of now, the gems are downloaded to `~/.rvm/gems/<ruby-version>/cache`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## gem fetch

So, something like `$ gem fetch gosu` ... this will leave `gosu-0.7.14.gem` in the current directory.

This will work even if you have already installed it.

Comment: I liked the `gosu` fetch. Is exactly what I want to do :)

Comment: is it possible to resolve dependencies and fetch them too, without installing?

Answer (score 3):

Most of the gems are hosted on [github.com](http://www.github.com) right now, you just have to clone the repo.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes it is.** Browse to the package's page on RubyGems.org and follow the download link.

Eg. from https://rubygems.org/gems/pony to https://rubygems.org/downloads/pony-1.4.gem