# Is it possible to download a platfrom specific Ruby gem without installing it?

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems

I read a answer the `gem fetch` answer on this question [is-it-possible-to-download-a-ruby-gem-without-installing-it-automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401653/is-it-possible-to-download-a-ruby-gem-without-installing-it-automatically). But windows I do not always get the windows gem.

Using `gem install gosu --remote` installs the windows version `Successfully installed gosu-0.7.15-x86-mswin32-60`.

When downloading using `gem fetch gosu` I get `Downloaded gosu-0.7.15` which is the linux version and can not be installed on my windows PC.

Asking for the specific gem with `gem fetch gosu-0.7.15-x86-mswin32-60` and similar tries yields `ERROR:  Could not find gosu-0.7.15-x86-mswin32-60 in any repository`

Any ideas as to how to get the correct version for my PC when using fetch versus install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ gem fetch --help
Usage: gem fetch GEMNAME [GEMNAME ...] [options]

  Options:
    -v, --version VERSION            Specify version of gem to fetch
        --platform PLATFORM          Specify the platform of gem to fetch

  Local/Remote Options:
    -B, --bulk-threshold COUNT       Threshold for switching to bulk
                                     synchronization (default 1000)
    -p, --[no-]http-proxy [URL]      Use HTTP proxy for remote operations
        --source URL                 Use URL as the remote source for gems

  Common Options:
    -h, --help                       Get help on this command
    -V, --[no-]verbose               Set the verbose level of output
    -q, --quiet                      Silence commands
        --config-file FILE           Use this config file instead of default
        --backtrace                  Show stack backtrace on errors
        --debug                      Turn on Ruby debugging


  Arguments:
    GEMNAME       name of gem to download

  Summary:
    Download a gem and place it in the current directory

  Defaults:
    --version '>= 0'
```

You should be able to do

```
$ gem fetch gosu --platform x86-mswin32
```

Or simply go to the [download page](http://code.google.com/p/gosu/downloads/list).